# Python concurrent logging to avoid disk bottleneck in code

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, python-asyncio

I'm not super familiar with asyncio, but I was hoping there would be some easy way to use asyncio.Queue to push log messages to a Queue instead of writing them to the disk, and then have a worker on a thread wait for these Queue events and write them to disk when resources are available. This seems pretty widely necessary, as logging is a huge bottleneck in a lot of code but isn't always needed in real time. Are there any pre-existing packages for this or can anyone with more experience write a short example script to get me started? NOTE: This needs to interface with existing code, so making it all packaged in a class would probably be preferred.

Comment: It sounds like you might want `queue.Queue`, not `asyncio.Queue`. asyncio is single threaded.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see that highlighted in documentation. It looked like they had moved queue.Queue at first glance!

Answer (score 1):

It's handled in the standard library in recent Python versions. See [this post](https://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/improved-queuehandler-queuelistener.html) for information, and the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler). This functionality predates `asyncio`, and so doesn't use it (and doesn't especially need to).

For Python 2.7, you can use the [logutils](https://pypi.org/project/logutils/) package which provides equivalent functionality.